# How to force iOS device to determine it's orientation via gyroscope?

Tags: ios, swift, uiviewcontroller

I have a situation where my app sometimes forces particular view controllers to appear in a particular orientation.

The only way I've found to do this is to set the device orientation manually, and tell the app to attempt to rotate itself like this:

```
switch (forceOrientation){
    case Orientations.PORTRAIT:
        let value = UIInterfaceOrientation.portrait.rawValue
        UIDevice.current.setValue(value, forKey: "orientation")
        UIViewController.attemptRotationToDeviceOrientation()
    case Orientations.LANDSCAPE:
        let value = UIInterfaceOrientation.landscapeLeft.rawValue
        UIDevice.current.setValue(value, forKey: "orientation")
        UIViewController.attemptRotationToDeviceOrientation()
    default:
        break
}
```

This works just fine.  However, once I close this view controller, and go back to the previous one I am still in the forced orientation regardless of how the device is being held.  Is there a way to set the orientation value to 'dirty' or something and have it auto detect?

I have tried setting the orientation value to `UIInterfaceOrientation.unknown.rawValue` and then attempt rotation, but this doesn't work.

I am using swift 4.1

**-- Edit --**

To clarify what I'm doing a bit more:

When my view controller is created, it sets itself to be the root view controller (so that it's rotation settings will actually work, otherwise the root behaviour is what's used)  At some point during it's initialization, it can be told that it should be oriented in a particular way.  If so, then it does the above code, and also set's it's orientation mask appropriately.  I am using these overrides:

```
public override var shouldAutorotate: Bool{
    return allowOrientationChange // this is set at some point after initializing
}

public override var supportedInterfaceOrientations: UIInterfaceOrientationMask {
    return orientationMask // this defaults to orientationMaskAll but is overridden 
}
```

When closing the view controller, the previous root controller is added back in as the root.  (But it is still rotated to whatever was forced, and does not update unless you move the device around)

Answer (score 0):

You can override `var supportedInterfaceOrientations: UIInterfaceOrientationMask { get }` and set it up in a way that returns the available orientations you want at any given time.

Basically, have this property return a variable that correlates with your `forceOrientation` enum.

See https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uiviewcontroller/1621435-supportedinterfaceorientations for details.

To force a rotation, you could do:

```
let previousOrientation = UIDevice.current.orientation  
let value = UIInterfaceOrientation.landscapeLeft.rawValue
UIDevice.current.setValue(value, forKey: "orientation")
//Rotates all view controllers
UIViewController.attemptRotationToDeviceOrientation()

//Find all UIViewControllers that need to be locked,  I recommend using a protocol


guard let appDelegate = UIApplication.sharedApplication().delegate, 
      let window = appDelegate.window, 
      let root = window.rootViewController,


else{
    fatalError("error")
} 
var viewControllers : [UIViewController] = []()
if root.presentedViewController != nil {
    viewControllers += [root.presentedViewController]
}
viewControllers += root.children
viewControllers.filter{$0 as OrientationLocked}.forEach{ vc in
  vc.orientationMask = ... //whatever previousOrientation isn't
}

//undo rotation
UIDevice.current.setValue(previousOrientation, forKey: "orientation")
UIViewController.attemptRotationToDeviceOrientation()

//View controllers that had been filtered are now rotated, where as anything underneath were treated as if a rotation did not happen
```

...
    any view controller that can be locked, needs this protocol

```
protocol OrientationLocked {
    var orientationMask : UIInterfaceOrientationMask 
}
```